# Unable to print a CSV file using Flink Table API

Tags: java, csv, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am trying to read a file with 34 fields in it to be printed on console using Netbeans. However, all I am able to print is the schema. Because the option to print is missing in this particular version of Flink used with csvreader.

Please see the code and help me understand where I should correct. I would have used `CSVReader`, inbuilt API but turns out it does not support more than 22 fields and hence resorted to using Table API. Also tried using `CsvTableSource` version 1.5.1 Flink, but no luck with syntax. As the `.field("%CPU", Types.FLOAT())` kept giving error for type float not recognised symbol.
My main aim is to just to be able to read the CSV file and then send to a Kafka topic, but before that i want to check if the file is read, no luck yet.

```
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Table;
import  org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.sources.CsvTableSource;
import org.apache.flink.types.Row;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Types;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;
import org.apache.flink.table.sinks.CsvTableSink;
import org.apache.flink.table.sinks.TableSink;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.java.Slide;


public class CsvReader {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment (env);
CsvTableSource csvTableSource = new CsvTableSource("/home/merlin/Experiments/input_container/container_data1.csv",
            new String[] { "%CPU", "MEM", "VSZ", "RSS", "timestamp",
    "OOM_Score", "io_read_count", "io_write_count", "io_read_bytes", "io_write_bytes",
    "io_read_chars", "io_write_chars", "num_fds", "num_ctx_switches_voluntary", "num_ctx_switches_involuntary",
    "mem_rss", "mem_vms", "mem_shared", "mem_text", "mem_lib", "mem_data", "mem_dirty", "mem_uss", "mem_pss",
    "mem_swap", "num_threads", "cpu_time_user", "cpu_time_system", "cpu_time_children_user",
    "cpu_time_children_system", "container_nr_sleeping", "container_nr_running",
    "container_nr_stopped", "container_nr_uninterruptible","container_nr_iowait" },
            new TypeInformation<?>[] {
                    Types.FLOAT(),
                    Types.FLOAT(),
                    Types.FLOAT(),
                    Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT(),
                                            Types.FLOAT()
                            });// lenient

    tEnv.registerTableSource("container", csvTableSource);
    Table result = tEnv
        .scan("container");
        System.out.println(result);
                result.printSchema();


      }
    }
/*tEnv.toAppendStream(result, Row.class).print();         
result.writeToSink(null);print();
            env.execute();*/
```

This is the output

```
root
 |-- %CPU: Float
 |-- MEM: Float
 |-- VSZ: Float
 |-- RSS: Float
 |-- timestamp: Float
 |-- OOM_Score: Float
 |-- io_read_count: Float
 |-- io_write_count: Float
 |-- io_read_bytes: Float
 |-- io_write_bytes: Float
 |-- io_read_chars: Float
 |-- io_write_chars: Float
 |-- num_fds: Float
 |-- num_ctx_switches_voluntary: Float
 |-- num_ctx_switches_involuntary: Float
 |-- mem_rss: Float
 |-- mem_vms: Float
 |-- mem_shared: Float
 |-- mem_text: Float
 |-- mem_lib: Float
 |-- mem_data: Float
 |-- mem_dirty: Float
 |-- mem_uss: Float
 |-- mem_pss: Float
 |-- mem_swap: Float
 |-- num_threads: Float
 |-- cpu_time_user: Float
 |-- cpu_time_system: Float
 |-- cpu_time_children_user: Float
 |-- cpu_time_children_system: Float
 |-- container_nr_sleeping: Float
 |-- container_nr_running: Float
 |-- container_nr_stopped: Float
 |-- container_nr_uninterruptible: Float
 |-- container_nr_iowait: Float
```

And this is another version of code, which too did not work

```
package wikiedits;

import static com.sun.xml.internal.fastinfoset.alphabet.BuiltInRestrictedAlphabets.table;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.Types;
import org.apache.flink.types.Row;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSink;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment;
public class Csv {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment (env);
//TableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment (env);

    CsvTableSource csvTableSource = CsvTableSource
    .builder()
    .path("home/merlin/Experiments/input_container/container_data1.csv")
    .field("%CPU", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("MEM", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("VSZ", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("RSS", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("timestamp", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("OOM_Score", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("io_read_count", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("io_write_count", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("io_read_bytes", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("io_write_bytes", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("io_read_chars", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("io_write_chars", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("num_fds", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("num_ctx_switches_voluntary", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("num_ctx_switches_involuntary", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("mem_rss", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("mem_vms", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("mem_shared", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("mem_text", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("mem_lib", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("mem_data", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("mem_dirty", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("mem_uss", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("mem_pss", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("mem_swap", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("num_threads", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("cpu_time_user", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("cpu_time_system", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("cpu_time_children_user", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("cpu_time_children_system", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("container_nr_sleeping", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("container_nr_running", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("container_nr_stopped", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("container_nr_uninterruptible", Types.FLOAT)
    .field("container_nr_iowait", Types.FLOAT)
    .fieldDelimiter(",")
    .lineDelimiter("\n")
    .ignoreFirstLine()
    .ignoreParseErrors()
    .commentPrefix("%")
    .build();
// name your table source
tEnv.registerTableSource("container", csvTableSource);
Table table = tEnv.scan("container");
DataStream<Row> stream = tEnv.toAppendStream(table, Row.class);
// define the sink as common print on console here
      stream.print();
             // env.execute();

  }
}
```

New edit If I had to pass it onto either a Kafka topic and then into a function call? This is what I tried:

```
DataStreamSink<Row> stream = addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer09<>( "my-second-topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));
//DataStreamSink<Row> stream = tEnv.toAppendStream(table, Row.class).print();
 stream.map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;
    public String map(String value) throws Exception {
    SendToRestAPI sendrest= new SendToRestAPI(value);
    String String1= sendrest.converttoJson();  

    return "Stream Value: " + String1;
  }
})
.addSink(new FlinkKafkaProducer09<>( "my-second-topic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)); /*.print();*/

env.execute();
  }
 }
```

The stream.map line throws error:

```
Cannot find symbol:method Map
```

Comment: What's in your csv file?

Comment: The csv file contains 34 fields with floating numbers. All 34 of them are digits basicaly@Sam

Comment: so "1.44, 3.22, 5.66"... etc? In proper csv format? Is excel / google sheets / similar happy to open this file?

Comment: @Sam 0.6 0 18244 3280 1512312018 0 122 11 0 0 98134 1783 4 56 1 3358720 18681856 2887680 999424 0 524288 0 495616 805888 0 1 0.02 0.01 0 0 1 0 0 0 0

Comment: As your delimiter is a space you should make sure to set it, look here https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/table/sourceSinks.html#csvtablesource

Comment: @Sam, I have used another version of flink in the first code, because the version you mentioned failed to work for me, due to errors already mentioned in the beginning. Please check the edit

Comment: Just make sure you look up to docs for CsvTableSource and use the longer constructor, or a Builder, to set your delimiter properly.

Comment: @Sam I have edited the present version, and now the code compiles without any errors. But while running it gives the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/java/ExecutionEnvironment at at wikiedits.Csv.main(Csv.java:32) which is final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

Comment: This jar has that class - make sure you have it

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-java/1.5.1

Comment: Yes, I cross checked, it reads version 1.5.1 and still gives the same error

Comment: @Sam Although this program refuses to exexcute in netbeans IDE, in terminal I was able to run the second version of the code successfully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177079/discussion-between-merlin-sundar-and-sam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code:

```
package example.flink;

import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.Types;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.java.StreamTableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Table;
import org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.table.sources.CsvTableSource;
import org.apache.flink.types.Row;

public class TestFlink {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment (env);

        CsvTableSource csvTableSource = CsvTableSource
                .builder()
                .path("container_data.csv")
                .field("%CPU", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("MEM", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("VSZ", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("RSS", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("timestamp", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("OOM_Score", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("io_read_count", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("io_write_count", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("io_read_bytes", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("io_write_bytes", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("io_read_chars", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("io_write_chars", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("num_fds", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("num_ctx_switches_voluntary", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("num_ctx_switches_involuntary", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("mem_rss", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("mem_vms", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("mem_shared", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("mem_text", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("mem_lib", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("mem_data", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("mem_dirty", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("mem_uss", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("mem_pss", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("mem_swap", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("num_threads", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("cpu_time_user", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("cpu_time_system", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("cpu_time_children_user", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("cpu_time_children_system", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("container_nr_sleeping", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("container_nr_running", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("container_nr_stopped", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("container_nr_uninterruptible", Types.FLOAT)
                .field("container_nr_iowait", Types.FLOAT)
                .fieldDelimiter(",")
                .lineDelimiter("\n")
                .ignoreFirstLine()
                .ignoreParseErrors()
                .commentPrefix("%")
                .build();
        // name your table source
        tEnv.registerTableSource("container", csvTableSource);
        Table table = tEnv.scan("container");
        DataStream<Row> stream = tEnv.toAppendStream(table, Row.class);
        // define the sink as common print on console here
        stream.print();
        try {
            env.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

With these libraries (some likely redundant):

```
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.7.25'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-clients_2.11', version: '1.5.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-table_2.11', version: '1.5.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-core', version: '1.5.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-java', version: '1.5.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-streaming-scala_2.11', version: '1.5.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-streaming-java_2.11', version: '1.5.1'
compile group: 'org.apache.flink', name: 'flink-runtime_2.11', version: '1.5.1'
```

Is running at least. I'm not sure if it gives the output you need, but it is almost exactly what you put in your latest edit, but is working in an IDE. Does that help?

If your delimiter is still a space remember to change `.fieldDelimiter(",")`

Comment: yes it does work for me in the terminal (by submitting the jar to flink method), but not in a Netbeans IDE. And yes, I have the exact versions of flink and others, you have listed above.

Comment: I don't have netbeans but it is working in intellij with gradle

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the `Table` into a `DataStream` to print it. The easiest way to do this is to convert it into a `DataStream<Row>` as follows:

```
DataStream<Row> stream = tEnv.toAppendStream(result, Row.class);
// print the stream & execute the program
stream.print();
env.execute();
```

See the [documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/table/common.html#convert-a-table-into-a-datastream-or-dataset) for more details.

Comment: I had tried this in my code already but it keeps giving me an error cannot find symbol "variable table" when i copy yours as it is. And when I try to write "result, Row.class it throws an error that time too. Also it asks me to add import according to netbeans, however that fails too.

Comment: You need to add `env.execute();` to start the program.

Comment: I did. still nothing. It says cant find methodtoappend(table, class<row>) and Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.toAppendStream

Comment: Change the line to `StreamTableEnvironment tEnv = TableEnvironment.getTableEnvironment (env);`.

Comment: Hey I tried what you mentioned, the code compiles fine but however, when running, the error is: 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/java/operators/Keys
 at at CsvReader.main(CsvReader.java:86) which is  DataStream<Row> stream = tEnv.toAppendStream(result, Row.class);

Comment: I have made a new edit in the code where I try to send the datastream into Kafka topic and then into a function call. But it fails with an error. Do you know the right method to instantiate the call? The main problem is here that the Row elements have to be sent as float[ ]